# Having trouble using mysql-connector in Python with Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

I'm creating a Python webapp with Flask that interfaces with a database. In testing and development, I was just using Laragon, and SQLAlchemy had no issues with that. However, I'm now trying to deploy, and the production database uses a CA certificate for connecting. I have the certificate, and I'm trying to use mysql-connector in order to connect with that certificate. No matter what I do, though, I always receive the error of "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'". This is my connect function.

```
        try:
            connect_string = "mysql+mysqlconnector://(blank for this post)"
            ssl_args = {'ssl_ca': '(blank for this post)'}
            self.engine = db.create_engine(connect_string, connect_args=ssl_args)
            self.connection = self.engine.connect()
            self.metadata = db.MetaData()
            self.covidata = db.Table('userdata', self.metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=self.engine)
        except SQLAlchemyError as err:
            print(err)
            return False
```

If I run `pip list | grep mysql`and `pip3 list | grep mysql` they both return the same output: mysql, mysql-connector-python-rf, and mysqlclient are all installed.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is this enough information for some help?

Comment: Try to uninstall `mysql-connector` then install `mysql-connector-python`.

Answer (score 0):

You should using PyMySQL:
    sudo apt install python3 python3-dev

Dependency library:
    sudo apt install python3 python3-dev
    sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev libmysqlclient-dev